# How to make an assert window in QT

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, qt4, embedded, assert

I currently have a very long running GUI-Application in QT. Later that application is going to be tested and run on an embedded device without a keyboard in full screen.

For easier debugging I have a custom assert macro, which allows me to ignore certain asserts (may include known buggy parts I have to work around for now) etc. For the time being I just print something on the console such as "Assertion: XXXX failed; abort/ignore". This is fine when I start the application within a console, but ultimately fails when I run it on the final device. In that case the assert will just block the main thread waiting for input and make the GUI hang badly without hope for recovery.

Now I am thinking about how to remedy this situation. One Idea is to just have the assert crash, as the standard assert does. But I do not really like that Idea, since there are a lot of know problems, and I've always found ignorable asserts very helpful when testing applications. Also I would have to put the messages into a separate file, so I can later see what happened while testing. Reading these files afterwards is possible, but I would prefer a simpler way to find out what went wrong.

The other idea was to make a window instead. However the asserts may be triggered in any thread and I can only create new windows in the GUI thread. Also the main event loop may be blocked by the assert, so I cannot be sure that it will handle the events correctly. I would somehow need a fully responsive stand-alone window in a separate thread, which only handles a few buttons.

Is this somehow possible in QT4?

Answer (score 1):

You may post events to main thread to display dialog and wait for an answer from non-gui threads, or just display dialog if current thread is app thread

```
int result = -1;
if ( QTrhead::currentThread() == QCoreApplication::instance()->thread() )
{
    result = AssertHandler->ShowDialog(where, what, condition);
}
else
{
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(AssertHandler, "ShowDialog", Qt::QueuedBlockingConnection, Q_RETURN_ARG(int, result), Q_ARG(QString, where), Q_ARG(QString, what), Q_ARG(QString, condition);
}

if (result != 0)
{
     // handle assert
}
```

The AssertHandler is QObject based class with slot `int ShowDialog(const QString &where, const QString what, const QString &condition)`. It should display dialog with assert data and buttons assert/ignore. Returns 0 when user pressed ignore, otherwise returns non zero value.